# Python Telegram Bot. Get message to which given message replies

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I want to develop a Telegram bot, that acts as a bookmarking system. It should process commands that reply to other messages. The instance:

[image]

I use `python-telegram-bot` for development and it seems that there is no way to see that message to which `/important` replies. I found the `Update.message.reply_to_message` object, which works only when a user replies to a message from the bot itself.

```py
def important_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    reply_to_message = update.message.reply_to_message
    if reply_to_message is None:
        logger.error('reply_to_message is None. But it shouldn\'t.')
        update.message.reply_text('There is no message attached. Try again.')
        return
    # ... business logic
```

Is there any way to get `reply_to_message` attribute (or an alternative) for all the replies? Thanks in advice;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. `reply_to_message` seems to fire regardless of whether the original message was sent by the bot or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It only worked when a user replied to the bot. My issue was that the bot had [Privacy Mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) enabled. Once I disabled it with [Botfather](https://t.me/BotFather) via `/setprivacy` and then it worked.